# Why do the conserved charges in the case of SSB of a global symmetry not exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, correlation-functions

Reading [*"From Linear SUSY to Constrained Superfields"*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2441) by Komargodski and Seiberg, I got a bit confused regarding the existence of the conserved charges in a theory with spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) of a global symmetry:

More precisely, in the second-to-last paragraph on page 1 we have

> *"When a global symmetry is spontaneously broken, the corresponding conserved charge does not exist **because its correlation functions are IR divergent**. However the conserved current and even the commutators with the conserved charge do exist."*

I know that in the case of global SSB we have $Q|0\rangle\neq0$ for the conserved charge $Q$. However, I don't have any insight about the correlation functions. Could somehow $Q|0\rangle\neq0$ imply something like $||Q|0\rangle||=\infty$ or $\langle Q\rangle\rightarrow\infty$? And how could one see that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called the Fabri-Picasso theorem. Their argument requires both the vacuum and the charge $Q$ to be translationally invariant: $P |0\rangle = 0$, and $[P, Q] = 0$.

The argument goes as follows: Since the charge originates from a symmetry, then according to Noether's theorem:

$$Q = \int d^3x j_0(x)$$

Consider the correlation function of the charge with itself:

\begin{align}
 \langle 0| QQ |0\rangle& = \int d^3x \langle0|j_0(x) Q|0\rangle  \\ 
& =\int d^3x \langle0|e^{iPx}  j_0(0) e^{-iPx} Q |0\rangle \\ 
             & =\int d^3x\langle0| e^{iPx}  j_0(0) e^{-iPx} Q e^{iPx} e^{-iPx}|0\rangle\\
& =\int d^3x \langle0| j_0(0)  Q |0\rangle  
\end{align}
The integrand in the r.h.s. does not depend on the position, therefore its value is proportional to the total space volume, thus
$$||Q|0\rangle||^2 = \infty$$
Thus the operator $Q$ does not exist in the Hilbert space unless $Q|0\rangle = 0$.

However, the commutators of $Q$ with the fields for example exist because by Noether's theorem, they generate the symmetry, in other words the right hand sides of:

$$[Q, \phi] = \delta \phi$$

exist, since they are the symmetry transformed fields.